# What is the point of unicode escape sequences in identifier names in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, unicode, escaping, identifier

JavaScript allows for having unicode escape sequences in identifier names... for example:

```
var \u0160imeVidas = "blah";
```

The above variable starts with the (croatian) letter Š, so that the complete name of the variable is "ŠimeVidas".
Now, this is neat, but what's the point?
Is there any scenario where this feature may be of any use?

Comment: Interesting, I did it in Chrome and it broke *console.dir(window)*.

Comment: Good point, @TimTheTinker. since it's `window['ŠimeVidas']`, a variable named `ŠimeVidas` is possible.

Comment: Broke? What do you mean?
I ran console.dir(window) and the ŠimeVidas variable is listed as a property... it is the second one from the bottom in the list (the last one is \_\_proto\_\_)

Comment: @Šime: that's strange, the global object won't expand for me to see any properties at all - Chrome 5.0.375.127.

Comment: I updated to 6.0.472.53 today. Can it be that that's the reason LOL?

Comment: @Šime: I expect so.  I haven't updated to the beta yet because I read there are some scripting related issues with Stack Overflow - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63067/google-chrome-repeatedly-displays-stack-overflow-works-best-with-javascript-enab.

Comment: It went out of beta yesterday. Under Tools > About Google Chrome there should be an Update button.

Comment: @Roy Tinker Could you write your comment above in form of an answer, so that I can accept is as the answer for this question? I will accept the answer: "It's to allow any string as a key in an object".

Answer (score 3):

Let’s say you’ve got a library stored in UTF-8 and that the author choose to use non-ASCII characters in the APIs. Then, let’s say that—for some reason—you need to access this library from a file stored in ASCII. Allowing the Unicode escape sequences in identifiers allows you to do that. There could be other such scenarios, but that’s one example.

Answer (score 2):

The only use I can think of for using the unicode escape sequence when declaring variables is for obfuscation.  You can, of course, type the following for the same variable:

```
var ŠimeVidas = "blah";
```

Now, if you were to refer to this variable with a random character in the string replaced with the unicode escape sequence, it would be much more difficult to search for and find those references.  Of course, like most other obfuscation technique it would be easily reversible.

If you wanted to use a unicode character that isn't mapped to an <kbd>Alt</kbd>+Num combination, it could save time on searching for the key code in charmap (or your OS' equivalent).  Not great for saving bytes, though.